# Find the probability that at least one of the event occur

Tags: probability

The probability that event M will not occur is 0.8 and the probability that event R will not occur is 0.6. If events M and R cannot both occur, which of the following is the probability that either event M or event R will occur?

Comment: can you edit your post to include what you have tried?

Comment: I Tried the following approach.
P (Either of the events) = 1 - P(neither of the events) = 1 - (0.8*0.6) = 0.52

Comment: tried to include your attempt in your post. posts without attempts are closed pretty quickly on this site.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(M)=1-0.8=0.2$$$$P(R)=1-0.6=0.4$$$$P(M\cap R)=0 \mbox{ $($since the events $M$ and $R$ cannot both occur})$$
$$P(M\cup R)=0.2+0.4=0.6$$

Therefore, the probability that either event M or event R will occur is $0.6=\dfrac35$

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am confused why the answer can't be
P (Either of the events) = 1 - P(neither of the events)
                                      = 1 - (0.8*0.6) 
                                      = 0.52
Can you please explain.
Thanks

Comment: @AmitDey We need to determine the probability that either event M or event R will occur

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
& M & \neg M \\\hline
R & 0 & A \\\hline
\neg R & B & C
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{cases}
A+C &=& 0.8 \\
B+C &=& 0.6 \\
A+B+C &=& 1
\end{cases}$$

Required probability is $A+B$.

Answer (score 0):

Start out with writing the relevant information.

$P(M’) = 0.8$, $P(R’) = 0.6$, $P(M \cap R) = 0$.

You are looking for the probability $P(M \cup R)$

$P(M \cup R) = P(M) + P(R) - P(M \cap R) = (1 - P(M’)) + (1 - P(R’)) - 0 = 0.2 + 0.4 = 0.6$

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

The following formula should be able to solve your problem:

$$P(M \cup R)=P(M)+P(R)-P(M\cap R)$$

Note that we can't say that $P(M^c \cap R^c)=P(M^c)P(R^c)$ as $M$ and $R$ are not independent. In fact, if $M$ happens, we know that $R$ won't happen.